# Definition of mini-skirt in Yabia Omer YD 6:14

Tags: women, clothing, tznius-modesty, leniencies, hacham-ovadia-yosef

In Yabia Omer YD 6:14, Rav [Ovadia Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadia_Yosef) ruled that it is preferable for a woman to wear women's pants than to wear a "mini-skirt" (חצאית-מיני). He writes that a full skirt is preferable to both.

In the beginning of the responsum (וברור..."‏") he explicitly rejects the opinion of the Peri Megadim (OC MZ 75:1) that the body part שוק (which he assumes a woman must cover) refers to the thigh, while accepting the opinion that it refers to the calf.

His concluding line is:

> ובמקום שלא ישמעו לנו הבנות ללבוש חצאיות או שמלות המכסות את הברכים, יש להעדיף מכנסים על חצאיות ושמלות קצרות, עד שיוכלו להשפיע עליהן ללבוש בגדי צניעות ככל בנות ישראל הכשרות
>   And in a place where the women won't listen to us to wear skirts or dresses which cover the knees, one should prefer pants to [short] skirts or short dresses, until one can influence them to wear modest clothing like all Kosher Jewish women. (my translation)

Why is R' Yosef willing to accept a skirt which only covers the knees but not the calf?

- Is he saying that he prefers an uncovered שוק to wearing pants?

  - Is he relying [Bedieved](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/759) on the opinion he rejected earlier in the responsum without saying so? (Did I miss it?)
  - Is he just making a cost-benefit Tzniut analysis? If so is his conclusion due to leniency regarding שוק or stringency regarding pants? (This would mean that men could not recite Shema in front of a women dressed like that.)
- Is he implicitly assuming that the skirt which covers the knees is being worn with opaque socks/leggings which cover the calf? (This would mean he preferred full pants to skirts which don't cover even legging-covered-knees, and all the more so to skirts which don't cover the entire calf if worn without opaque socks/leggings.)

**My question is about R' Yosef's referenced opinion. Not about anyone else's opinion about anything.**

Comment: I did not see it inside,but it seems that since there is a strong opinion which is followed by many that the shok is called the thighs then it is at least acceptable,however if it it is above the knee then there is no halachik opinion who allows it.

Comment: @sam It's actually a ridiculously weak opinion, though you are correct that it is followed by many. As I said though ROY explicitly rejects this opinion in no uncertain terms in the beginning of the responsum. You are indicating my first suggested resolution as listed in the question.

Comment: He does mention (in section 1): וברור שירך חמור יותר משוק

Comment: it really seems from the qoute of the tshuva that it is at least keep to the knee,but if one would have asked him personally he would have said to the calf,it is more of what the people do in the street.

Comment: @sam I'm not sure what you mean. Is he not issuing his own psak here? If he thinks pants are better than leaving the calf uncovered then he should just say so. What's the problem?

Comment: he writes that he disagrees lchumrah to the calf ,but there is an accepted opinion who allows to the knee,he even writes "like all the kosher daughters of Israel" which would imply that if some paskened like the opinion which holds like the knee they are still kasher but if one would ask him he would hold to the calf.

Comment: @sam I think that you are reading into things that aren't there, but if you think it is correct you can post it as an answer I guess. He never writes there is an accepted opinion who allows to the knee (only a rejected one), and note he doesn't even mention the Mishna Berura by name (to show you how irrelevant he thought it was). How do you know "the clothing of the kosher daughters of Israel" is skirts that cover only knees worn without leggings? Perhaps option 2 or 1b (in my question) is correct.

Comment: +1 its a good question ,have to see it inside,however, I do believe my comments are relevant to the distinction.

Comment: My read of the *t'shuva* is as follows: Mini-skirts exist for the purpose of *pritzus*. Wearing them violates *b'chukoseihem lo seileichu* and also creates a major stumbling block for men. Pants, at least in our day and age, don't exist for the purpose of *pritzus* (especially loose-fitting pants), although they are still immodest garments (though not *beged ish*). Pants are therefore preferable. R' O.Y. didn't seem to consider the possibility of opaque socks, and mentioned explicitly that nylon stockings accomplish nothing....

Comment: My read of R' O.Y. is that skirts past the knee, though only acceptable according to opinions (that R' O.Y. rejects) that say *shok* is the thigh (e.g. *P'ri M'gadim*), are a problem because "covered areas" are left uncovered. However, my guess is that he would not consider this as bad as pants, especially if he considers a skirt that covers just past the knees a "regular skirt": ‎לבישת מכנסים... כי בגדי שחץ הן ומעוררות תשומת לב מיוחדת לרואיהן יותר מאשר שמלה או חצאית רגילה. So I think 1b is correct. (Perhaps it is both "due to leniency regarding שוק" and "stringency regarding pants").

Comment: @Fred Good eye on רגילה, though I'm not sure how you can know for sure that a regular skirt isn't one which covers to the ankles. Nowhere does he specifically use ארוכה to refer to one that reaches the ankles. Additionally, this would still leave the teachers of the classrooms who sit opposite students showing calves (a point he mentions early on) in a bind, because presumably they will be unable to say Divrei Torah.

Comment: _I cleaned up some comments_. @Fred and sam: I did not limit answers to concrete proofs from ROY's other writings (though, those would be most welcome and convincing). If you have an idea and want to argue for it in an answer, you are welcome to. Try to bring as much textual and/or logical support for your positions as you can.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know for sure that רגילה means skirts past the knees, but his remark at the end (that you quoted: ובמקום שלא ישמעו לנו הבנות ללבוש חצאיות או שמלות המכסות את הברכים) at least makes me think there are רגלים לדבר. | As far as your point about teaching Torah, yes the teachers would apparently still be in a bind if the girls wore skirts past the knees, esp. considering R' O.Y.'s wording (והן יושבות לפניו ברגלים מגולות דהוי תרתי לריעותא - which would seem to include calves). Maybe he would suggest improvising barriers with desks, or something.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Yalqut Yosef [182:8](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_50.html) and [21:3](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_82.html)

Comment: @DoubleAA Those rulings in *Yalkut Yosef* seem more stringent than their purported source in *Yabia' Omer*.

Comment: @Fred I agree completely. They might support an implied opaque stockings read, though.

Comment: Intriguing title https://seforimblog.com/2015/07/blog-pos-14/

Comment: Okay this one's fun https://s1.kikar.co.il/data/auto/addonsmgr/fa/pn0y1z8o.jpeg

Comment: This is considerably less fun https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/yosef-rabbi-ovadiah

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20230806231327/https://www.ebay.com/itm/394794595318 and pic https://web.archive.org/web/20230806231232/https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/cb8AAOSwO9Rkz4En/s-l1600.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Looking at both the question and the answer found in Yabia Omer, it is not speaking about adult, married women. It is discussing teenage girls in school only. It specifically is dealing with teenage girls who show up at a religious school in mini-skirts and refuse to listen to the school directors about wearing modest skirts. From the outset, this is portrayed as a *cost-benefit* situation.

Rabbi Yosef doesn't say what he disagrees to from the Pri Megadim. He says that this response is not the place to get into it. Simply looking at the Pri Megadim there are several different viewpoints mentioned about what שוק means. He tries to say that in some places שוק can mean thigh. The source he points to for this is Mishnah Chullin 10:4.

This may be what Rabbi Yosef is objecting to because Chullin is discussing the שוק of an animal. In regard to the laws of modesty, it is about the שוק of a human being, which is different. The variation in anatomy for human beings is described in Mishnah Oholot 1:8.

For human beings, שוק means calf, not thigh.

The closing paragraph (8) makes clear that לכתחילה girls should not be permitted to wear long pants because they are *garments of haughtiness*, meaning they draw attention to the form of woman and accentuate it. He emphasizes that for girls who wear mini-skirts, efforts should be made to influence them in a pleasant way to wear modest skirts and dresses that also cover the knees *also when they are sitting*. As discussed in the earlier paragraphs that means when standing the skirt is well below the knee (more than 4 inches). It is only in situations where the girls refuse to wear skirts of that length that long pants are preferable to mini-skirts.

As Rabbi Yosef points out in paragraph 3 based on the Bach to Yoreh Deah 182, pants worn to protect from the weather are permissible for women. That was part of the question posed at the beginning. In paragraphs 3-6 he also points out that the concept of *beged ish* does not apply for a variety of reasons enumerated.

It is in paragraph 7 where he runs through the cost analysis citing Sotah 48,  Sefer Chassidim 176 and the response of the Rashba among others. As he points out, there are valid opinions that long pants are covering the *ervah* and are acceptable in certain limited circumstances.

1) Rabbi Yosef is not saying he prefers uncovered שוק to wearing pants.

2) He is not relying *bedieved* on an opinion he rejected earlier. (Assuming you are referring to the Pri Megadim comment)

3) Yes, he is making a *cost-benefit* analysis. No, it is not about a leniency regarding שוק. I don't understand what you mean by a *stringency regarding pants*.

4) He discusses stockings with skirts, but I think it was not dealing with opaque ones but rather transparent stockings like nylons. Nylons are not considered as covering. The question of opaque stockings would require additional review.

Comment: "stringency regarding pants" means the reason he prefers knee-skirts to pants is because pants are so bad (the alternative is because uncovered calves isn't so bad). So which value is he compromising on?

Comment: I'm not sure how the summary parts in this answer help answer the question.

Comment: I don't understand how you can hold points 1 and 4 at the same time. He clearly prefers knee-skirts to pants. Whether or not there are stockings too is debatable, but you can't hold there are no stockings AND he does not prefer uncovered calf to wearing pants. Hence I don't understand what you are trying to say. -1. Think of it this way: if he doesn't prefer uncovered calves to pants, then he should prefer pants to knee-skirts where there aren't opaque stockings, which is not his ruling here.

Comment: @DoubleAA You keep trying to use your expression 'knee-skirts'. That is not in the response of Rabbi Yosef. He is talking about modest skirts that completely cover. Also, in keeping with your request in the question,  none of this answer is how I hold. It is simply what Rabbi Yosef wrote. As he says clearly, long pants are a compromise but not because of ervah. Review paragraph 7 closely and you will see it.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the expression 'knee-skirts'. I _am_ using it. They refer to skirts which cover the knees but not the calf. It is those skirts that R Yosef recommends instead of pants (I don't know what you mean by "He is talking about modest skirts that completely cover"; please be more explicit). The question is why, ie "Why is R' Yosef willing to accept a skirt which only covers the knees but not the calf?" (I never thought any of this was what you hold, and indeed I couldn't care less what you hold.)